# Hat Dash leaderboard update times

Tags: bug, winter-bash, hat-dash

I made it onto the Hat Dash leaderboard this morning, with a score of 1362, after the leaderboard reset. [image]

At the time of this question, the leaderboard also lists me as having a little over 5 minutes of game time, with only 12 games played (post leaderboard reset)

[image]

However, I got that score at 1:14 UTC, as it is listed, and, in the 3 hour time span since then, have gotten multiple higher scores, and much more play time and games played, as shown here:
[image]

Some of these scores I made over an hour ago, but I have not seen any update to the leaderboard, either for my scores, or my play time. However, I have since seen updates to the leaderboard for other people's times and records. Is the leaderboard lagging behind? Is it a viewer issue, that only shows up for me? Or is there some other reason why my results have not been updated, in relation to being flagged for exploits or cheats?

Comment: As an aside, I don't believe this to be a duplicate of other questions asking similar things, for the sole reason that their answers do not seem to apply here. My other scores are still listed, so I don't seem to be banned.

Comment: Were all of these times legitimate? No cheating involved?

Comment: @YaakovEllis Yes